# I got a response from PayPal but I can't insert it in my database

Tags: wordpress

I can receive a response from PayPal but I can't insert it in my database. I'm using WordPress. What's wrong with WordPress?
Jere's my code and this is working when I navigate to this page and this page where the PayPal IPN response will go but its not working I receive the PayPal response but it's not inserting in my database. It's only working when I go to my paypal_ipn module. What is wrong in PayPal and WordPress?

```
    global $wpdb;
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$prod_id = $_POST['custom'];
$tblname = "my_table";
           $wpdb->insert($tblname,
           array(
                "id" => "$txn_id",
                "email" => "$payer_email ", 
                "prodid" =>  "$prod_id"
                ), 
                array("%s", "%s", "%d")
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your passing strings to a decimal conversation with a space in it. I imagine that'd cause some issues. Also removed unneeded string concatination.

```
   global $wpdb;
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$prod_id = $_POST['custom'];

$tblname = "my_table";
           $wpdb->insert($tblname,
           array(
                "id" => $txn_id,
                "email" => $payer_email, 
                "prodid" =>  $prod_id
                ), 
                array("%s", "%s", "%d")
                );
```

Comment: sorry my fault my code is working it can insert in db my only problem is its not inserting when paypal ipn response arrive its not triggering my insert statement in wordpress its only working when i navigate to that module.

Comment: Did you validate your IPN is properly set? Is that the full code?

Comment: file_put_contents('test.txt', var_export($_POST, true)); i usually use this if there is a response from paypal and there is a response and i store it in my textfile.and im trying to insert in my database but wordpress is not inserting it.